# Need help using values from one list to find values for another list

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def collectData():
print ("Please use correct spelling\n")
print("Choose what game type this is")

getGameType = input(" FFA: 1\n 1v1: 2\n 2v2: 3\n 3v3: 4\n 4v4: 5\n")
if getGameType == "1":

 FFAPlayerList = []

 getFFAMaxLen = (int)(input("How Many players were in this FFA?: "))

 print("Please enter playername as well as placing, seperated by a comma\n(playerName,placing) One player per entry. \n")

 while len(FFAPlayerList) < getFFAMaxLen:
     getFFAPlayers = input("format: playerName,Placing::: ").split(',')
     FFAPlayerList.append(getFFAPlayers)

 with open("C:\\Users\\Twinklenugget\\Documents\\NQGroup\\Databases\\NQMasterDatabase.csv", 'r') as ffaDatabaseExtract:
     reader = csv.reader(ffaDatabaseExtract)
     ffaDatabaseList = list(reader)

     FFAPlayerList.append(ffaDatabaseList)

 print (FFAPlayerList)






collectData()
```

Forgive the formatting, it's actually all correct. I am relativly new to python and coding in general. My goal is to be able to take the values stored in FFAPlayerList (the player names) and use those strings to look for the same strings in ffaDatabaseList. After it finds the same strings from ffaDatabaseList I then need to take values from the second column from ffaDatabaseList and append them into FFAPlayerList. How exactly would I go about doing that? Even a pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to find in `ffaDatabaseList` players also found in `FFAPlayerList` and then add them again in `FFAPlayerList`. Is that what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, the user inputs values that get put into FFAPlayerList I want to be able to check to see if they are in ffaDatabaseList.